# First countable, second countable, and Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, second-countable, first-countable, lindelof-spaces

I've studying the countability chapter in Schaum's *General Topology* and in the book, the author goes over first countable, second countable, and Lindelöf spaces. Once the author covers the definitions of each kind of space, he goes on to state two things:

- **Proposition 9.2** A second countable space is also a first countable space
- Every second countable space is a Lindelöf space

So, when I first saw this, I thought that every Lindelöf space must therefore be first countable, but I know that's not true since $(X,\mathcal{D})$ where $X$ is an uncountable set and $\mathcal{D}$ is the discrete topology is first countable but not Lindelöf. So therefore, we can't state that every Lindelöf space is first countable.

In trying to understand the relationship between these three kinds of spaces, I made a diagram that I think nicely illustrates what I can gather about the relationship between these three.
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTq2P.jpg)

Once you click the link, you'll see I've made a Venn diagram illustrating what I think is the relationship between these three. In this way, from this illustration, we can gather two things:

1. Second countable spaces belong to both first countable spaces and Lindelöf spaces
2. There are examples of first countable spaces that are not Lindelöf and Lindelöf spaces which are not first countable.

Am I leaving out anything here or is this a good way to visualize the relationship between first countable, second countable, and Lindelöf?

Comment: You are leaving out the possibility of a Lindelöf space that is first countable but not second countable.

Comment: Compact spaces are Lindelof. Any space $X$ is a dense open subspace of a compact space  $X\cup \{p\}$ where $p\not\in X$ if $X$ is not compact. If $X$ is not 1st (or 2nd) countable then neither is $X\cup \{p\}$... See "Alexandroff compactification".

Comment: @AndersBeta. Two examples of a Lindelof space that's 1st-countable Lindelof but not 2nd-countable: (1): The Sorgenfrey Line. (2): The order-topology of the lexicographic (dictionary) order on $[0,1]\times [0,1].$

Comment: Your alleged counterexample to "every Lindelöf space must be first countable" is actually a counterexample to the converse.

Comment: @AndersBeta How would a space be Lindelof without being second countable? Without a countable base, how could every open cover of the space have a countable subcover?

Comment: A space could be compact (and have a **finite** subcover for every open cover), yet not second countable.

Comment: @SunRoad2 The Sorgenfrey line is Lindelof and first countable without being second countable. (This is the same as the topology on the real line generated by half-open intervals $[x,y)$.) The double arrow space (which is closely related) is compact and first countable, but not second countable.